# How to add .Net Standard Nuget package into .Net 4.5 Framework Project?

Tags: c#, .net, ffmpeg, .net-4.5, nuget-package

I am trying to install https://www.nuget.org/packages/FFMpegCore/4.8.0#dependencies-body-tab (FFMpegCore) Nuget package in my .Net 4.5 Console project. But unfortunately, getting the below error

> Error NU1202  Package FFMpegCore 4.8.0 is not compatible with net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5) / win-x86. Package FFMpegCore 4.8.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0) ScreenCapturer  C:\source\repos\ScreenCapturer\ScreenCapturer.csproj    1

Actually trying to stream .png images to FFmpeg input pipe & then convert them as a video.

P.S: Kind of new to this FFMpeg as well. So any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plugin requires at least *.NETStandard,Version=v2.0* to be used. There is nothing you can change here. As you can see at [.NET Standards documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard?tabs=net-standard-2-0), this means your application requires .NET Framework 4.6.1 or higher to be compatible.

This means you need to upgrade your .NET Framework target version of your application to fulfill the requirement. Another option would be to write a .NET Core application.

Comment: Thanks, @Fruchtzwerg for the insight that worked. One more question which Nuget package would be feasible to proceed further (FFmpegCore vs FFmpeg.Autogen). -> "Trying to stream .png images to FFmpeg input pipe & then convert them as a video". from a c# console app .Net Framework 4.6.1

Comment: I think there is no "right way"here. I would prefer to use FFmpegCore since the community is bigger and the project seems to be more active.